# Support results in association rules are less than 5%

Tags: sas, market-basket-analysis, enterprise-miner

I am facing an issue with Association rules. I have a dataset which consists of transaction ID and ProductID
I have edited the variable and changed TransactionID role to "ID" and productID role to "Target"
The minimum support % is set to 5%. But when i run the association i m getting support percentages less than 5%. What might be wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What SAS product is this in?

Comment: Hi Joe, This is SAS Enterprise miner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the highest frequency count of any product in the productid column and get 5% value of that that frequency count. The number you get should be the threshold transaction count till which enterprise miner should be showing you the result. Support percentage is based on the maximum frequency count of target column and not on the entire transaction dataset.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks sushil. This makes perfect sense.